# Why does my img tag create two requests?

Tags: jquery, html, image

HTML snap code:

```
<div id='div'><img /></div>
```

jQuery code:

```js
$("#div > img").click(function(){     
    var url = "path/to/img";
       $(this).attr("src", url);
       return false;    
});
```

In Firebug I can see only one request, 
but the `img` (from Firebug) is not the one displaying (from browser).
From my server, there are two requests.

Even if I set `img` `src` first, when clicked, it will still make two requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an image will cause a request made to the server to load its src. Changing its src will cause a request to be made for the new source.

Add the image to the document with JavaScript instead of having a placeholder there to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the image tot he page with jQuery. You can use the following code to achieve this:

```
var img = $('<img></img>');
img.attr("src", url);
$("#div").html("");
$("#div").append(img);
```

You should replace the following in your code with the code above:

```
$(this).attr("src", url);
```